# getApplicationContext method in android

Tags: android, android-context

I am writing an Android App using Android Studio that uses `XMLPullParser` to read an xml file from file. Now I need to use `getApplicationContext` method in this class, but when I declare a Context variable can't resolve this method. How can I do it?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

public class XMLPullParserHandler {

private List<App> apps= new ArrayList<App>();
private App app;
private String text;

public List<App> getApps() {
    return apps;
}

public List<App> parse(InputStream is) {

    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser  parser = factory.newPullParser();

        parser.setInput(is, null);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagname = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("app")) {
                        app = new App();
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("app")) {
                        apps.add(app);
                    }else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                        app.setId(Integer.parseInt(text));
                    }  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        app.setTitle(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("activity")) {
                        app.setActivity(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("location")){
                        app.setLocation(Integer.parseInt(text));
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("address")){
                        app.setAddress(text);
                    }

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    return apps;


   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constructor to `XMLPullParserHandler` that takes a `Context` (or an `Application`) as a parameter. Store that value in a field on `XMLPullParserHandler`. Use that field as needed.

Comment: public XMLPullParserHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }   is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor and add context as a parameter in it, somewhat like this.

```
Context ctx;
public XMLPullParserHandler(Context context)
{
this.ctx=context;
}
```

Now use `ctx` as context where ever you want